# How to assign json values to normal variable in node js?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express, mongoose

I'm working in node js with mongodb and i'm getting json data  from mongodb server but i cannot assign the json to respective values.

```
var express=require('express');
var mongoose= require('mongoose');
var bodyParser=require('body-parser');
var url = require('url');
var jsonfile = require('jsonfile')

var db='mongodb://20.0.0.34:27017/sashcash_dev';
mongoose.connect(db)
var campDetails=require('./campign');
var app=express();

var urlLink = 'http://localhost:8000/Details';


app.get('/Details',function(req,res){


    campDetails.findOne({ _id: '5820683fa4a41ae34de407b4' }, 'title type ' , function (err, result) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(result);
        res.send(result);
    })
})
```

I need this result data out of the Details port

```
var title=result.title;
var type=result.type;

var parseUrl=url.parse(urlLink,true,true);
var type=parseUrl.query.type;
console.log('href',parseUrl.href);
console.log('href',parseUrl.hash);
console.log(type);

var obj=json.parse(urlLink);
console.log("type",obj.type);
console.dir(jsonfile.readFileSync(file))

app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended:false
}))

app.listen(8000,function(req,res){
    console.log('the listening port is 8000');
})
```

Comment: `but i cannot assign the json to respective values.` what does that mean? What is the problem that you are actually having?

Comment: I'm getting the json values in (result) but when i try to get the result value out of that function .exec() it failed. All i want is result .title and result.type has to be assigned to var title & var type .